# Qt C++ initialize a QStringList class member

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have a class member of type `QStringList`. I had a guess that when this class is instantiated, `nex` instance get such a `QStringLsit` with no elements in it.
I have a function that should fill in this `QStringList` on user interaction. However, I see with debugger that class member does not exist at function call. What could it be all about? Is there a way to initialize the `QListString` that I may be missing here?

Comment: Is this function a class member? When do you call it? Show some code.

Comment: It's impossible that a "class member doesn't exist". Also, if you don't use a pointer for the member (which you shouldn't), the member will be default-constructed, which results in an empty QStringList.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question and show the code that you believe is not working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QStringList` should get initialized on the creation of your object automatically (unless it is a pointer). I see two possible explanations for the debugger's behaviour:

- Your object (of which you call the function) doesn't get created before the function call; that means that the `this` pointer is invalid when the function gets entered. This may be the case if you call the function on an uninitialised pointer to your class.
- The debugger just doesn't show the `QStringList` member correctly.
- If your member is of type `QStringList*` (a pointer), it doesn't get automatically initialised on object creation. Then you'd need to do `list = new QStringList();` in the constructor. But I doubt that you need a pointer to a string list here.